# REST API, Get Work Item ID from CD Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

In Azure DevOps, I have a CI pipeline which generates an artifact. As soon as the Pull Request gets approved, it triggers a CD release pipeline. In the CD pipeline, I have added a PowerShell task to perform some REST API functions.

I want to retrieve the associated work item ID from the artifact which was built during the CI phase.

I am using this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20work%20items%20refs?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) by feeding the Build ID (32 characters, e.g. *de5017b5bf537a92397f54f5570783bf32cc6bf*), however the result is: 404 - Page not found.

Any ideas? Maybe this API is used only in the CI build pipeline? Many thanks.

**Edit**

I got the Build ID from **Initialize Job** log of the CD pipeline and added a variable `$(Release.Artifacts.ALIASNAME.BuildID)`.

[image]

Comment: could you post your `Invoke-RestMethod` snippet and your full `$url` argument to see whats going on here?

Comment: @MarTin yes sure, this is the [url](https://dev.azure.com/naregk/txproject/_apis/build/builds/de5017b5bf537a92397f54f5570783bf32cc6bfc/workitems?api-version=5.1)

Comment: The build id not should be 32 chars, from where you take it?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, I edited the original post with my reply and a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Maybe this API is used only in the CI build pipeline?

No, the API not just limited in build pipeline. It can also be used in release.

Since you did not shared your script about powershell, so I can share your my sample. I just tested it and its succeed on my side.

```
$buildid=$(build.buildid)
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/build/builds/$buildId/workitems?api-version=5.1"
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
} -Method GET

Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

The `build.buildid` is the environment variable of relevant build with this release.

In the log of this pipeline, you will see the result of API :

[image]

**Updated:**

I try to check your logs details from backend, and found error. In the log of your initialize job, you can see that the build definition name is same with your repos name. This means that the source of this release is Repository instead of Build:

[image]

**Updated 2:**

Please select **Continuous deployment trigger** in the trigger type of release if you want to this release triggered after PR completed. For pull request, completed means that the changes is allowed to merge into the target branch. This is the precondition of **Continuous deployment trigger** and **continuous integration**.

And also, for the source of release, please choose relevant **Build**. In **Trigger** tab of build definition, please enable **Enable continuous integration**.

At this time, after the pull request, the changes from feature branch will merge into the target branch. And then, it will trigger the CI build. After build succeed, the artifact will produced and trigger CD release. The release will take this artifacts and deploy it into stages.

Comment: For the URL, you can also use the predefined release variables : `$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/build/builds/$(Release.Artifacts.ALIASNAME.BuildId)/workitems?api-version=5.0"`

Comment: What's you error? Did you enable **Allow scripts to access the OAuth token** also?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT Thanks for your suggestion! Do you mind I add your suggestion into my answer?

Comment: Thank you for your code but sadly it is not working. This is a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/hyD204f.png) of the PowerShell task. And [here](https://i.imgur.com/BNBNH7N.png) is the output in the log.

Comment: @naregkar Try in the first line: `buildId="$(build.buildid)"` (with `" "`)

Comment: The issue should caused by your buildid value. Do you mind add one script `Write-Host $buildid` and disable the last two line of script to see your build id value? Refer this: https://imgur.com/a/xFgWx0F

Comment: @naregkar I also test with trigger release by build automatically, the build id still be a normal number and the api is succeed. Do you mind share more details about your release?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk that helped for the first part. [This](https://imgur.com/FpjMHHS) is the result. However, when I add the invoke, again page not found [error](https://imgur.com/y35G8fN). It seems as you mentioned, the build ID is wrong, should be an integer. No clue why it is retrieving as GUID.

Comment: Maybe the build id is not an integer since I have chosen Azure Repository as the source [type](https://imgur.com/a/3lK9zzj) and not Build Type in the CD pipeline?

Comment: Okay. That's make sense. That's because your source is repos instead of build. That's why I did not find `BUILD_BUILDURI` in your release Initialize log when I check your release logs from backend

Comment: This should be the root cause about this issue.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT, exactly, I tried and changed the artifact and it now retriving the build id as required. The reason I had selected Repositovy over Build is because I want to perform a CD whenver a PR is completed. Will I be able to achieve that with the Build artifact? Thanks a ton!

Comment: @naregkar Sorry to say that “No you can’t”. You can compare the error build id with your commit id. You will find that while you want to use pr to trigger the release, in fact, the build id is  commit id.

Comment: While you trigger release with pr, the artifact of release is commit rather than the artifact which from build. You can see this at the page of [one release record](https://imgur.com/6gjQIvW) .

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT yes they are exactly the same. Do you think there is any workaround? Or I should try to find a way to extract the BuildId from the CI and use it in my PowerShell task in CD?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there has an work around while the release trigger by PR. Since the method you are using is trigger CD directly after PR completed, this means that the release does not need through CI. So, there will no artifacts which from build exists in release.

Comment: Why don't you set after PR completed, CI executed first. And after CI succeed, it will produce artifacts and trigger the CD then. At this time, the artifacts is the real one which from build result instead of repos commit.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT so in the CD [pipeline](https://imgur.com/hkFM2RG), I choose Continuous deployment trigger or the pull request trigger? I want the CD be triggered ONLY when the PR is completed. Moreover, just for info, I have added a build validation policy for master branch using the same CI pipeline .

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check my updated 2.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT many many thanks! It worked seamlessly and the build ID (proper format) is available on the CD pipeline!

Comment: Aha! Very glad to hear that!! You are so welcome. My pleasure to help you:-)